# Rails multiple layouts or html in database

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, performance, markdown

I am using rails 4 and have an efficiency question.

I am creating dynamic pages that all have different layouts. I was thinking that there are only two good options to handle this.

1. Store the html in the database, maybe as markdown using redcarpet gem etc.
2. Create a separate layout for every page (this would amount to around 500 layouts pages currently)

My question is which one is more practical, efficient and most importantly scalable.

My fear is that storing html will slow down the app considerably once a decent amount of users access it.

Thanks for any suggestions
Jean

Comment: what project needs 500 different layouts? :O

Comment: I could restrict the layouts to a more reasonable amount. I guess my real question if efficiency and scalability suffers when storing html

Comment: could you maybe show an example *how* the layouts will differ. I think the problem lies much more in that fact than in the db management.